# Comment threads moved to chat should not count as recently active rooms when sorting chat rooms by activity

Tags: bug, chat

I hang out in [a room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art) hosted on Math.SE.

The creator of the room [noticed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39656675#39656675) that the room wasn't showing up on the [list of rooms hosted on Math.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com).

[image: list of rooms on Math.SE]

I was like *huh? why not? it isn't private or anything.* Turns out that it was showing up on [the 4th page of rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&page=4&host=math.stackexchange.com), behind a bunch of comment threads moved to chat.

This is, I assume, not expected behavior. Can the room please show up in the actual active order when viewing rooms by active sort?

Comment: Did it start as an *Invite user to room* room as opposed to a simple *create a new room*?

Comment: I also noticed that based on [list of "starred posts" page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art?tab=stars), it started as a private room. I don't know if it's related or not though.

Comment: @rene - that's a good question. I'm not sure, but I don't think so.

Comment: @Elias - I think that's just confusion on the author's part.

Comment: @Mithrandir you are a mod there, right? Can't you see that in the magic chat mod tools?

Comment: @rene - I don't think that shows on the chat mod tools (and not a Math.SE mod - Literature.SE mod).

Comment: Did you try to press ctrl+W?  .... Okay, I'm out of here ...

Comment: @rene is most likely right, the room started as a "Room for [User A] and [User B]" and those appear after ordinary rooms (i.e. rooms created by "create a new room" button) by design.